# How do i split text to a different column or remove a text from the original column?

Tags: vba, excel, text, split

I've copied a column of data starting from D9 to D-whatever, the copied data have both decimal value and text. The data varies in each cell in column D

### Example

D9 : 1675.87 L/s 
D10 : 1555.87 L/s 
D11 : 1635.87 L/s 
This is my code i tried..

```
    Dim c As Collection, K As Long
     Set c = New Collection
     K = 9
     On Error Resume Next
     For Each r In Range("D9:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)
     ary = Split(r.Text, ",")
     For Each a In ary
     c.Add a, CStr(a)
     If Err.Number = 0 Then
     Cells(K, "E").Value = a
     K = K + 1
     Else
     Err.Number = 0
     End If
     Next a
     Next r
     On Error GoTo 0
```

**I want to split the data so that it will be D6 1675.87 and E6 L/s OR remove the L/s completely.**

I know this is simple for most people but I'm relatively new at this so any help would be good. Thank you. You are much appreciated.

Comment: Read about `Split` function -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: @Dawid thanks for replying . I've tried that it doesn't work. My data didn't change. Sorry.

Comment: Look for example in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So test that :

```
Sub SplitValues()
Dim aSplit As Variant

With ActiveSheet
    For I = 2 To Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        aSplit = Split(Cells(I, "D"), " ", 2)

        'Write in D and E columns (erase data already in D)
        Cells(I, "D") = aSplit(0)
        Cells(I, "E") = aSplit(1)

        'Write in E and F columns (don't erase data already in D)
        'Cells(I, "E") = ArrSplit(0)
        'Cells(I, "F") = ArrSplit(1)
    Next I
End With

End Sub
```

You may simply use a built-in Excel tool :

> In **Data** tab, **Convert** tool :
>
> 1. Choose Delimited
> 2. Chose space as Separator

and just enjoy

No need for VBA there, if you want just take a look at the [split function there](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: YOU DID IT! OMG THANK YOU SO MUCH @R3uk

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the Data tab on the Ribbon you will see a Text to Columns tool.

Select the data you want to split then click on Text to Columns.

In Step 1, select the Delimited option and click Next.

In Step 2, select just the Space delimiter and click Next.

In Step 3 you will see a preview of how your data will be split and have the option to select a column and not import it.

Answer (score 1):

Read about `Split` function -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

```
Sub LittleExample()

Dim ArrSplit As Variant

Cells(6, "D") = "1675.87 L/s"

ArrSplit = Split(Cells(6, "D"), " ")

Cells(6, "D") = ArrSplit(0) ' 1675.87
Cells(6, "E") = ArrSplit(1) ' L/s

End Sub
```

Comment: HI! Hello again @Dawid you code works only for the first value.

Comment: Yes, only for first value. I posted this example to let you know that way is working. If you need for a larger number of rows, try use `loop` -> http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html

Comment: i have tried to loop it in different ways buy i am unable to do it right. could you maybe try? p.s not all my data is 1675.87 L/s. it differs as it goes down the column

Comment: Edit you question and add more data from column D. Maybe we can find another solution. Also you can post code which you did not work

Answer (score 1):

As noted, `Split` is the easy way to do this.  If you know that you will always have a single space you can get all of the cells very quickly with

```
Sub SplitAndRewrite()

    Dim rng_start As Range
    Set rng_start = Range("D6")

    Dim rng_cell As Range
    For Each rng_cell In Range(rng_start, rng_start.End(xlDown))
        rng_cell.Resize(, 2) = Split(rng_cell, " ")
    Next
End Sub
```

Code works by iterating through a *contiguous* (uses `End`) column of values and applying `Split` on the .  It then takes the two values and pops them back on top of the cell using `Resize` to expand the output by one column.

`Split` returns an array so it can be quickly output back into the spreadsheet.